# Rename the object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I have an array of objects where I want to rename the key name as shown:

```
let Options = [{Code: 1, Label: 'abc'}, {Code: 2, Label: 'xyz'}, {Code: 3, Label: 'fgh'}];
```

I want to change the key 'Code' to 'value' as shown:

```
let Options = [{value: 1, Label: 'abc'}, {value: 2, Label: 'xyz'}, {value: 3, Label: 'fgh'}];
```

How I can accomplish the desired output.

Comment: Please do some research before asking. It is trivial to find similar questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using map like this:

```js
let Options = [{Code: 1, Label: 'abc'}, {Code: 2, Label: 'xyz'}, {Code: 3, Label: 'fgh'}];
const res = Options.map(elem => {
  elem.value = elem.Code;
  delete elem.Code;
  return elem;
});
```

Comment: value is undefine in the end result as {value: undefined, Label: 'abc'}

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: it worked for me: `const resultArray = Options.map(elm => ({ value: elm.Code, Label: elm.Label}));` Thanks!