# How to replace the object key name dynamically Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I want to rename the **factORLossTree** into **savefactORLossTree** dynamically inside the function from below payload.

I am getting below data on payload after submitting the form.

```
{
    "cluster":"Europe",
    "factory":"Caivano",
    "factoryId":"Caivano",    
    "factORLossTree":[
       {
          "skuid":"000000000067334539",
          "skuDescription":"MAG 55ml Mini PistHazelnut 8MP x6x120 EB",         
          "levelLosses":[
             {
                "level1":"Line Scheduling Losses",
                "variancePer":100
             }
          ],
          "isRowChecked":false
       }
    ],
    "submitType":"po"
 }
```

**Below is my code .**

```
saveOrUpdateORData() { 
    const formData = Object.assign({}, this.orLosstreeForm.value);
    if (formData.factORLossTree.length === 0) {
      this.dialogService.openDialog('Data Not Available');
      return false;
    }  
    console.log(formData,"formdata");
    return;   
  }
```

Expected Output

```
{
    "cluster":"Europe",
    "factory":"Caivano",
    "factoryId":"Caivano",    
    "savefactORLossTree":[
       {
          "skuid":"000000000067334539",
          "skuDescription":"MAG 55ml Mini PistHazelnut 8MP x6x120 EB",         
          "levelLosses":[
             {
                "level1":"Line Scheduling Losses",
                "variancePer":100
             }
          ],
          "isRowChecked":false
       }
    ],
    "submitType":"po"
 }
```

Can anyone please help me to do this.

Comment: _"...rename the factORLossTree into savefactORLossTree dynamically..."_ - What does this mean? What is the expected result? And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Andreas, I have added my expected output. i want if i post form values so before posting into API i need to rename  the key factORLossTree into savefactORLossTree

Comment: Duplicate of: [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key) or [Rename the object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544266/rename-the-object-key) or https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+object+rename+(property+OR+key)+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing! Worth mentioning that this issue is purely JS and has nothing to do with your framework (e.g. - Angular)

To the point: let's assume that your payload is stored in a variable called `payload`

First - check if the property exists. Then - replace it:

```
const propertyName = 'put the property name here'
const newPropertyName = 'put the new property name here'

if (payload.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
  payload[newPropertyName] = payload[propertyName]
  delete payload[propertyName]
}
```

Why this is working? Because we are creating another reference to the original data before deleting the property. At the end we end-up with one reference having the updated name

If (from some reason) you need to clone the data, follow this pattern instead:

```
if (payload.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
  const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload[propertyName]))
  payload[newPropertyName] = clone
  delete payload[propertyName]
}
```

I assume that your property always contains an object. If the type of the property is primitive (e.g. - `number`, `string` or `boolean`) you can just skip the cloning phase all together (primitives are copied by their values while only objects are handled by their reference)

Comment: I tried below code bt it is showing error on propertyname Cannot find factorlosstree if (formData.hasOwnProperty(factORLossTree)) {
      formData[savefactORLossTree] = formData[factORLossTree]
      delete formData[factORLossTree]
    }

Comment: I suggest that you will use a sandbox to apply the code and see the results. Once you get  how it works - you may make the additional adjustments to your code in order to resolve the issue. also you should use `'factORLossTree'` instead of just `factORLossTree`.. just saying

Comment: Why did you add an answer instead of a close-vote as an [obivious duplicate](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+object+rename+(property+OR+key)+site%3Astackoverflow.com) of on of the many "rename a property" questions here on SO?

Comment: Hi @Andreas. Do to the complexity and low up-voting of the answers for this topic (at least those I found) - I thought a straight forward answer may help. If you feel otherwise, you can mark it as duplicate.. NP

Comment: After OP edited the question I definitely would close it as duplicate, but I've "wasted" my CV for the previous unclear version of the question...

Comment: I think OP should always get a chance to redeem the question .. (in question) like they did here. Out of curiosity what does CV stand for in this context @Andreas ?

Comment: CV = close vote